# Make decisions based on checked buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, button

Using bootstrap, I have a set of buttons :

```
<div id="first" class="panel panel-primary panel-width">
    <div class="panel-heading">Yes/No Question</div>
    <div id="answer" class="panel-body">
    <div class="btn-group-sm" role="group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" name="CusYes" class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">No</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

and I want to check whether the user checked yes or no. This is how I check in a js file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Submit").click(function() {
var CusYes = $("input:button[name=CusYes]:checked").val();

if(CusYes ==== "Yes") { alert ("it works!");}
  });


});
```

and it used to work before changing to bootstrap but now it doesn't work.

added code for submit :

```
<button id="Submit" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submit !
  </button>
```

Comment: added code for submit

Comment: Is it on server? could you provide the link? It would better for us to debug

Comment: no it's not on server.

Comment: @tyrell_c Check out the answer, if still any issues feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an `input`-tag anymore, so it doesn't match.

Easiest is to just give it an id and use that to retrieve the value.

```
<button type="button" name="CusYes" id ="cusyes" class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>

var cusyes = $("#cusyes").val();
```

I guess this should also work:

```
var CusYes = $("button:button[name=CusYes]:checked").val();
```

Comment: Okay, you're using javascript powered bootstrap components I guess. Did you read the documentation for that component?

Comment: Yes. and I think either var CusYes = $("input:radio[name=CusYes]:checked").val(); or var cusyes = $("#cusyes").val(); should work. But I can't even get it to give me the value. I checked and the submit button works on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Single toggle](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-single-toggle) for this.

This is your button now:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
  Single toggle
</button>
```

A toggled button has an `active` class attached to it. So, on form submit all your have to do to get the active one is `$('button.active')`

Answer (score 0):

During adding bootstrap , your button not now radio button.
What you can do here is , on click of

```
    <button type="button" name="CusYes" class="btn btn-default commonclass">Yes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default commonclass">No</button>

$('.commonclass').off('click').on('click',function(){
   $('.commonclass').removeClass('active';)
   $(this).addClass('active');
});

$("#Submit").click(function(){
    // check for active class
    if($('.commonclass').find('.active').val() === 'yes'){
        alert('yes !');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, this will work for you.

In Bootstrap for `data-toggle="buttons-checkbox"` when the button inside it is clicked it will add `active` class to it (it will actually toggle on clicking multiple times), but if Bootstrap JavaScript not inserted properly, it might cause issues.

So i would prefer you to try this, it will surely work.

```js
$('#statusYes').click(function(){
$('#statusYes').toggleClass('active');
});

$('#statusNo').click(function(){
$('#statusNo').toggleClass('active');
});

$('button[id="Submit"]').click(function () {
    if($('#statusYes').hasClass("active"))
    {
        alert("Button with Yes is Active!");
    }
    if($('#statusNo').hasClass("active"))
    {
        alert("Button with No is Active!");
    }
    // Now if none are active
    if(!$('#statusYes').hasClass("active") && !$('#statusNo').hasClass("active"))
    {
        alert("None among Yes and No button is Active");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="first" class="panel panel-primary panel-width">
    <div class="panel-heading">Yes/No Question</div>
    <div id="answer" class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-group-sm" role="group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" aria-label="...">
            <button type="button" id="statusYes" class="btn btn-default">Yes</button>
            <button type="button" id="statusNo" class="btn btn-default">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="Submit" type="button" class="btn btn-success"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submit !</button>
```